# Links Selection Not Working in Using jQuery in Joomla Module

Tags: jquery, joomla

Good day everyone.

I'm building a Joomla module and trying to collect links using the following

```
menuLinks = jQuery('.menu .menu_items .menu_item a')
```

Problem is that menuLinks is empty (I confirmed with menuLinks.length). This worked fine when I used it outside joomla using just html and javascript.

A quick help will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Finally found something that helped:

```
jQuery('div').find('.megamenu .menu .menu_items .menu_item a').each(function() {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? Have you wrapped you code around document ready? Are you sure you're importing jQuery on your Joomla site?

Comment: No error in browser console, and yes I wrapped my code in document.ready and yes jQuery is being imported. I already tested all that, as a matter of fact the function that uses the links also works as I tested with a simple alert function. But alerting the length of the link gives 0.

Comment: Have as asked before, have you wrapped your code around jquery document ready? How are you adding the code? Using Joomla's `addScriptDeclaration()` method? Can you please provide some more details?

Comment: No I call addScript and run the JavaScript code externally.

Comment: Ok^^....And I will ask you again, have you wrapped it in [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) ?

Comment: I realized my error on my way home yesterday, I defined my objects outside document.ready and was trying to call a method that depended on one of them, thanks a lot for your help, I'm going to tick what you wrote below as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu .menu_items .menu_item').find('a').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        console.log(self.attr('href'));
    });
});
```

If you check your console, you will see that is shows all the links for each menu item.

Hope this helps

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you try adding `console.log($('.menu .menu_items .menu_item').html());` and let me know if anything gets displayed in the console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null mod_wetv_menu.js:13
MegaDropdown.handleMenuClick mod_wetv_menu.js:13
(anonymous function) mod_wetv_menu.js:183
b.extend.ready jquery-1.4.3.min.js:28
t

Comment: That's the error, sorry whitespace in comments is not working I would have structured it so you can see it one line after the other.

Comment: Apparently the classes are hidden from jQuery somehow. Still don't know why as I can see them in the elements tab.

Comment: jQuery('div').find('.megamenu .menu .menu_items .menu_item a').each(function() {
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        });